# EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup resetting value in custom editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an editor script which is supposed to allow me to change the texture of a tile (I'm making a game board). It works by creating a drop down menu with different "tile types", and then when I select a new tile type from the menu it will change the texture to the appropriate type.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Tile))]
public class TileEditor : Editor {

    enum Type {
        Blank,
        Portal
    }

    // Represents the type of tile this is
    Type type;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        Tile tile = (Tile)target;

        // Create a dropdown list of tile types
        type = (Type)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup ("Type", type);

        switch (type) {
        case Type.Blank:
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Resources.Load ("Materials/Blank Tile", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            break;
        case Type.Portal:
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Resources.Load("Materials/Portal Tile", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the lines where I set the materials, the drop down menu works as expected, but with those lines included, when I select Portal from the drop down it will change the texture for just a moment, and then both the texture and the menu will reset themselves back to the first item in the enum (Blank).

What is going on here, and how do I make my selections persist?

**Edit**

I've narrowed down the issue slightly. When I select the Portal type it executes the `Type.Portal` case, but then immediately `type` changes back to `Type.Blank` and it executes the `Type.Blank` case. So it seems something is changing my `type` variable between calls to `OnInspectorGUI()`.

Comment: Why not post your Tile  script?

Comment: @Programmer it's blank at the moment. Just an empty class.

Comment: Ok, what directory is your "Portal Tile" placed?

Comment: @Programmer `Resources/Materials`. The texture loads properly, and displays on the tile for a moment, but then reverts.

Comment: Interesting. Just wanted to make sure that Resources.Load is not null. And I was able to replicate the problem. It's weird. This looks like a bug.....

Comment: @Programmer Darn! I was hoping it wasn't a bug. Do you have any suggestions for what I might do to work around it?

Comment: It may not be a bug but check my answer for ways to fix this. I recommend *#2* as that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just two problems:

It resets to the first enum right away and when you save the scene and load it, it also resets to the first enum when you select the GameObject `Tile` script is attached to.

**Solution 1**:

Make `Type type` static. Simply change `Type type;` to  `static Type type;`.
This should fix the problem I described above.

*But then, you will realize that when you save and re-load your project, the enum is not saved. It resets to index 0 (Type.Blank).*

**Solution 2**:

I hardly work on Editor scripts but to my understanding, the `type` variable should be declared in the `Tile` script instead of the `TileEditor` script. Also, you should re-name that *Type* `enum` to something else. `Type` is part of C# standard API from the `System` namespace. Re-name it to something like `TileType` so that you won't confuse yourself in the future.

Declaring it in the `Tile` script should solve all your problems.

*Tile* script:

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TileType type;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

`TileEditor` script:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Tile))]
public class TileEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Tile tile = (Tile)target;

        // Create a dropdown list of tile types
        tile.type = (TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("TileType", tile.type);

        Debug.Log("OnInspectorGUI");

        switch (tile.type)
        {
            case TileType.Blank:
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Resources.Load("Materials/Blank Tile", typeof(Material)) as Material;
                Debug.Log("Blank");
                break;
            case TileType.Portal:
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Resources.Load("Materials/Portal Tile", typeof(Material)) as Material;
                Debug.Log("Portal");
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum TileType
{
    Blank,
    Portal
}
```

You can also improve this by adding a class that loads the materials *once* then store them in static variable. This will prevent having to load it each time the dropdown is changed. You can learn more about *Custom Inspector* [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector).

Comment: Oh my gosh. How could I have missed that? I was storing the tile type in the editor instead of the tile. That was dumb of me. But I don't think I would have figured it out without your help, thank you so much.

Comment: Its not dumb if you have not made Custom Inspector before. I thought that was the problem then verified after I saw [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector). You are welcome and happy coding!